# Get last row of View by couchbase query

Tags: python, rows, couchbase

i have a query which returns me a Viewobject with all the entries i want to process. I know i can iterate over this view Object so that i can use the single entries for my purposes.

Now i want to extract only the first and the last row. The first row is no problem because i can just iterate and break the loop after the first item.

Now my question is, how to get the last element from the View.

I tried by:

```
                for row in result_rows:
                    rowvalue = row[3].value
                    diagdata = rowvalue[models.DIAGDATA]
                    if models.ODOMETER in diagdata:
                        start_mileage = diagdata[models.ODOMETER]
                        start_mileage_found = True
                    break

                row = result_rows[len(result_rows)]
                rowvalue = row[3].value
                diagdata = rowvalue[models.DIAGDATA]
                if models.ODOMETER in diagdata:
                    end_mileage = diagdata[models.ODOMETER]
                    end_mileage_found = True
```

The second value i obviously wont get, because view has neither a length nor can i access the rows by a index. Has anyone an idea how to get the last element?

Answer (score 1):

You might run another request but with `descending=True` option, so that the server will stream results in reverse order.

Or you can convert iterator to array which basically the same a iterate through all values. I'm not a python expert, but it seems like `list(result_rows)` will do it for you. And when you are doing `len(...)` it probably doing it for you implicitly. There is [`rows_returned`](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-python-client-1.2.0/html/api/views.html#couchbase.views.iterator.rows_returned) method to get the number of rows without turning it to list.